# Stripe Payment Intent manual confirmation for testing

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing

I have a setup where the backend would create a Stripe Source, and pass the redirect url to the frontend for the user to be sent to to input the payment details and submit the payment. In the test environment there was also a url returned here where you could basically confirm an order with just a click of a button, and then handle the webhook.

Now I am trying to migrate to the Payment Intents and there is no redirect url anymore.
There is the client_secret that I can pass to the frontend and they can do all the confirmation, but for testing is there a way to somehow similarly to sources access this page?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for iDEAL, it's recommended to use webhooks to be notified of the payment along with automatic confirmation, since for example the customer's browser could close or their device might run out of battery etc, after authenticating the payment and before you can notify your backend to re-confirm the PaymentIntent [[0]](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment#web-fulfillment).

If you do want to use manual confirmation, you should follow the steps here : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment but create the PaymentIntent with `confirmation_method=manual` [[1]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirmation_method) instead.

`stripe.confirmIdealPayment` will automatically redirect the customer to that page to "authorize" or "fail" the payment.

If you want to handle the redirect manually instead of using `stripe.confirmIdealPayment`, I'd recommend taking a look at. : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment#web-handle-redirect

After the customer completes the payment on their bank’s website or mobile application, they will be redirected back to your website, and you can make an API call using the query parameters to confirm the payment.

For automated testing, you would want to save the response from Stripe the first time you test this flow manually (i.e. clicking "Authorized test payment" or "Fail test payment") via the test payment page, then simulate that subsequently.

If you want to get to the test authorization page as easily as possible for testing purposes, you can include the below parameters when creating your PaymentIntent. The response should contain the `next_action.redirect_to_url.url` parameter and opening that link in your browser will show the Stripe test authentication page.

cURL example

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
  -u sk_test_...: \
  -d amount=2000 \
  -d currency=eur \
  -d confirm=true \
  -d payment_method_types[]=ideal \
  -d payment_method_data[type]=ideal \
  -d payment_method_data[ideal][bank]=ing \
  -d return_url="http://localhost/return"
```

Comment: Hey, and how do I add the payment_method?
I have the event that you have on the bottom, that a new payment was created.
  "status": "requires_payment_method",

Comment: sorry, i slightly misunderstood the question before and edited my answer to reflect that. In essence, you'd want to follow the guide : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment.  `stripe.confirmIdealPayment` will automatically redirect the customer to that page to "authorize" or "fail" the payment.

Comment: Hey, sorry, your answer was right, the question is about manual backend implementation testing.
I create the payment intent and I see that in the dashboard, I just want to get to the test authorization page as easily as possible. 
I want to invoke what this does essentially: stripe.confirmIdealPayment without having to have some test app.

Comment: included a cURL example to show how you can get to the Stripe test authentication page as easily as possible. Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for =)

Comment: Yes, exactly, the curl example!

Comment: Would you have any reason not to return the redirect url to the front_end instead of the client_secret and letting them use stripe.confirmIdealPayment?

Comment: I think it's really a design decision and up to the engineering team to see what works best for them. For example, if I were using several different payment processors, and was already using manual redirects (with those other payment processors), I would continue to use that instead of stripe.confirmIdealPayment